# Delete files that are 5 days old using bash script

Tags: bash

I currently use a command that searches a directory and deletes 5 day old files.

`find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;`

I run it from the command line and it works fine. But when I put it in a `.sh` file it says `find /path/to/files*: No such file or directory`.

There is only two lines in the shell script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

How can I rewrite the script so that it works?
`

Comment: Make `/path/to/files*` `/path/to/files` The `+5` means the file was modified at least `6` days ago. When computing `n * 24` hours, the fractional part is discarded. so to be *Greater Than* `5` days old, it would have to be modified at least `6` days ago.

Comment: I tried `/path/to/files` and that did not work either. I got the same error: `No such file or directory`. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Normally the argument to `find` is the directory, not the files. `find` automatically searches all the files in the directory and subdirectories. If you give the filenames, you'll get that error if none of them exist (because the previous run of the script deleted them all).

Comment: Using `/path/to/files` is an absolute path. It will not matter where you run it from (command line or script) -- it will point to the same location within the filesystem. If the error is `error: No such file or directory` -- that's pretty self-explanatory... What does `ls -al /path/to/files` show??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

find /home/ubuntu/directory -type f -name 'filename*' -mtime +4 -delete
```

Here is an example:

```
find /home/ubuntu/processed -type f -name 'output*' -mtime +4 -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens if there are currently no files matching the wildcard, presumably because none have been created since you deleted them previously.

The argument to `find` should be the directory containing the files, not the filenames themselves, since `find` will automatically search the directory. If you want to restrict the filenames, use the `-name` option to specify the wildcard.

And if you don't want to go into subdirectories, use the `-maxdepth` option.

```
find /path/to -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'files*' -mtime +5 -delete
```

Comment: I am no longer getting an error but the files that are 5 days old are still in the directory (ie haven't been removed). Here is my code: `find /home/ubuntu -type f -name 'excel*' -mtime +4 -delete
find /home/ubuntu -type f -name 'csv_folder*' -mtime +4 -delete
find /home/ubuntu -type f -name 'processed*' -mtime +4 -delete` The directories are excel, csv_folder, and processed.